# Como utilizar o Javascript para limitar o número de checkboxes que podem ser selecionadas?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Olá, eu estou fazendo um mini-projeto no jsfidlle,
segue o link https://jsfiddle.net/elenderg/wzarrg06/
Existem vários botões e o usuário terá de selecionar um deles, conforme figura abaixo:
[image: botões]

Quando o usuário escolhe quantos números ele deseja apostar, a tabela com os números aparece. O problema é que minha função abaixo não está funcionando (coloquei o limite de 6 como exemplo, o correto seria o limite se ajustar de acordo com a opção selecionada pelo usuário. 
segue o código da função:

```
(function($){

var currentLimit=6;

$('div.limits > input[type=button]').on('click',function(){
  currentLimit = parseInt($(this).data('value'));
});

$('div.checks input').on('click', function(e){
    var totalChecked = $('input:checked').length;

    if (totalChecked > currentLimit){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
})
```

Outra coisa que eu acho que seria mais prática seria substituir as `checkboxes` por algum tipo de botão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primeira coisa que você deve fazer, substituir os `“` e `”` por `"`, isto está interferindo no seu HTML, então faça que os seus eventos inline recebam o parametro `event` como argumento.

segundo ponto, no método `myFunction` armazene a quantidade limite de inputs em uma variavel.

```
<button data-value="6" class='btn btn-info custom'onclick="myFunction(event)">6 (R$ 2,00)</button>

var limite = 0;
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = document.getElementById("tabela");
  x.style.display = "inline-block";
  limite = parseInt(event.target.dataset.value);
}
```

por fim implemente o método KeepCount...

```
var quantidade = 0;
function KeepCount(event) {
    if (event.target.checked && quantidade == limite) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    quantidade += event.target.checked ? 1 : -1;    
}
```

Segue o seu fiddle atualizado: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzarrg06/69/)

Comment: muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Veja estes dois exemplos:

```
$(document).on('change', '.shared', function() {
  var countShared = $('.shared:checked').length;
  if (countShared > 3 && $(this).is(':checked')) {
    alert("You have reached the maximum number of selectable checkboxes.");
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

[DEMO Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ggkzyw7v/)

ou

```
$(document).on('change', '.shared', function() {
    var countShared = $('.shared:checked').length;
    if(countShared > 3) {          //<-------------here is the difference
        alert("You have reached the maximum number of selectable checkboxes.");
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

[DEMO Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ggkzyw7v/2/)

Adicional:

[Exemplo com Jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Vg4ty/1/)

Espero ter ajudado;

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015422/jquery-how-to-block-checkboxes-for-checking-when-certain-condition-is-met

Comment: o primeiro exemplo está mais perto do que desejo, porém eu ainda estou determinando o limite de checkboxes, quando quem deveria fazer é o usuário, ao clicar sobre o botão. no mais, muito obrigado.

Comment: tentei trocar a minha função por esta, ajustando os valores, porém não as minhas outras funções não fucionaram...